# Duda en "positive lookahead assertion" para comprobación de contraseña JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
^(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[A-Z])(?=\w*[a-z])\S{8,16}$
```

Estoy empezando con expresiones regulares en js y entiendo que con `?=` puedes verificar si existe algún carácter, pero que función tiene `\w` en este caso, también he visto que utilizan el `.` en su lugar, quedando de la siguiente manera `?=.*\d`, entiendo su funcionamiento de manera independiente pero no se que papel desempeñan ahí.

Comment: Si buscas con google hay infinidad de páginas que te dicen que significa cada simbolo. Puntualmente podes jugar en https://regex101.com/ . \W significa que matchea algo que no es ni letra, ni dígito, ni guión bajo.

Answer (score 0):

The recomiendo usar alguna web tipo https://regexr.com/ donde puedes ver una explicación de que hace cada parte y escribir ejemplos para ver qué hace match.

Sobre tú consulta concreta `?=` cómo bien has dicho se llama positive lookahead.
Este tipo de operadores se usa solo junto a capture groups (`()`)

Un capture group sirve para eso... definir una expresión que al hacer match se guardará en una variable (`$1`, `$2`, etc..)

El positive look ahead es un operador que sirve para comprobar que una expresión la sigue otra expresión. Por ejemplo, si tenemos la cadena `Regexs are hard` y la expresión `Reg(?=exs)`

En este caso estamos haciendo match por `Reg` solo si va seguido de `exs`. Pero `exs` no forma parte del match ni se guarda como capture group.

Si la expresion fuese `Reg(?=x)` no tendríamos match. Pese a que `Reg` existe no está seguido de `x`.

Puedes conseguir el comportamiento contrario con negative lookahead `(?!)`

Siguiendo con las dudas `\w` es lo que se llama un "character class" y es una forma de escribir una expresión de una forma menos repetitiva.

`\w` hace match con cualquier letra y guión bajo. Por lo cual es el equivalente de escribir `[A-Za-z_]`*1
Existen otros como `\d` que es lo mismo que escribir `[0-9]`

Luego tenemos `.` qué significa cualquier carácter.

Y por último tenemos `*` y `+` estos siempre van después de una expresión.
Y como con ejemplos siempre queda todo mas claro...

Si tenemos la cadena `hola soy un gran ejemplo` y la expresión `\w` el resultado es que tendrás un match por cada carácter menos espacios.

Sin embargo, si la expresión es `\w+` el match será por cada palabra. El `+` significa haz match de la anterior expresión 1 o más veces hasta que haya un carácter que no haga match (en este caso los espacios)
El `*` es muy similar solo que significa 0 o más veces

*1 No es del todo cierto porque según las opciones de tu regex `\w` puede hacer match con carácteres utf-8

Comment: Está bien. 2 comentarios: `(?=...)` no es un grupo de captura, usa paréntesis pero es una estructura completamente diferente de `(...)`; y en JavaScript `\w` no coincide con absolutamente nada más que `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, solamente en otros lenguajes es que se puede modificar el comportamiento por flags.